# Merge rows values if the FK is same

Tags: pivot

I have a following table

| PK | NAME | FK |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | abc | 01FK |
| 02 | bca | 01FK |
| 03 | cab | 02FK |
| 04 | xyz | 03FK |
| 05 | yzx | 02FK |

I want to generate a new table where FK is the primary and the rest of the column(s) merge based on FK. So the end result looks something like this:

| FK | NAME |
| --- | --- |
| 01FK | abc, bca |
| 02FK | cab, yzx |
| 03FK | xyz |

Comment: [Help me write this query in SQL](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2976/32281)

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using?

Answer (score 6):

You can use STRING_AGG to solve this problem (SQL Server 2017):

```
SELECT FK, STRING_AGG(name, ', ') AS NAME FROM dbo.NotProvidedTableName
GROUP BY FK
```

If you are on an older version, you can use the FOR XML clause.

```
WITH CTE_TableName
AS (SELECT FK,
           Name
    FROM dbo.NotProvidedTableName)
SELECT t0.FK,
       STUFF(
       (
           SELECT ',' + t1.Name
           FROM CTE_TableName t1
           WHERE t1.FK = t0.FK
           ORDER BY t1.Name
           FOR XML PATH('')
       ),
       1,
       LEN(','),
       ''
            ) AS NAME
FROM CTE_TableName t0
GROUP BY t0.FK
ORDER BY FK;
```

For next time, please add scripts to create tables and testdata please. See also the link Erik suggested as comment.